# if a subsequence of cauchy sequence converges, then the whole sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis

I found a proof on here already. I get the general idea, but I'm not sure I understand the need to say $M=max${$N,K$}. Why wouldn't it be sufficient to just say $n,m>N$ and $n_k>K$?

existing proof:
[If a subsequence of a Cauchy sequence converges, then the whole sequence converges.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/662299/if-a-subsequence-of-cauchy-sequence-converges-then-the-whole-sequence-converges?rq=1)

Also, if $n_k$ is strictly increasing, is it possible to conclude either $K>N$ or $N>K$?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you know the definition of convergence? How would it look with two bounds on $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Here in the proof the $M=max\{N,K\}$ is needed because this the domain where both the inequalities hold.

Comment: But since "$n,m>N$ and $n_k>K$" is a conjunction, doesn't that inherently mean we are only talking about where both inequalities are true? Wouldn't "for all $n,m,n_k>M$" amount to the same thing as "for all $n,m>N$ and $n_k>K$"?

Comment: @chris yes we want both inequalities to be true i.e. we want to substitute $n_k$ in the other inequality. So the inequality on $n_k$ as well as $n$ should be valid